# Discord.py Editing channel name edit doesn't execute

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a simple a program that reads a state from a text file and renames a channel accordingly. Yet, I have tried every possible method I could find online and none of them worked. I have isolated the issue to `.edit()` which is very strange. Everything else seems to work perfectly until it reaches `.edit()`. Even weirder, it perfectly changes the name of the channel to "Online" but not to "Offline". I literally cannot figure out why this is happening and baffled by this.

Here is my code:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import tasks

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")
    status.start()

async def setname(state):                                         # crated a function to change name as last resort
    ch: discord.TextChannel = client.get_channel(947128272758648873)
    states = ["Offline", "Online"]                                # two channel names I want to change to
    await ch.edit(name = states[int(state)])
    print(state)
    
@tasks.loop(seconds = 10)
async def status():
    file = open("status.txt", 'r')
    content = file.read()
    await setname(content)                                        # content contains either a 0 or 1 

client.run('TOKEN')
```

The code doesn't give any errors, but just stops working (printing the state) when the text file is changed

I have tried:

- Checking if the state is being read from file (yes)
- Checking if the channel can be found (yes)

I might be misunderstanding how loop tasks work as I am new to discord.py

Thanks in advance

Comment: The ratelimit for changing channel names is 2 requests per 10 minutes per channel. You simply *can't* edit the name every 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful information not mentioned anywhere.